# append function doesn't work as expected (arangodb)

Tags: arangodb

These are few queries which I executed and the results. The fourth one throws error.

```
LET doc = DOCUMENT("sample/xyz")
RETURN doc.t==null
```

result: True   (as key xyz doesn't exist)

---

```
RETURN append(null,[1,2,2],true)
```

result : [1,2]  (unique values appended to empty list)

---

```
LET doc = DOCUMENT("sample/xyz")
return append(doc.t,[1,2,2])
```

result : [1,2,2]  ([1,2,2] appended to empty list)

---

```
LET doc = DOCUMENT("sample/xyz")
RETURN append(doc.t,[1,2,2],True)
```

throws **error** whereas **doc.t** should evaluate to **null** and result should be **[1,2]**.

The error that I got is here :

```
Query: Expecting type Array or Object (while executing) (exception location: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ArangoDB_Release/arangod/RestHandler/RestCursorHandler.cpp:131)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for getting back to you that late. 
This used to be an issue with ArangoDB 3.0; It doesn't happen with ArangoDB 3.1 / 3.2

I've added a test for this too, so it won't change in the future again.

In general, please file issues via github issues, not as a stackoverflow question.